# Efficient way to conditionally update values in 2 records in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table that contains 4 columns

```
id | category | score | enabled
1  |  news    |  95   |    t
```

`id` -- serial

`category` -- varchar

`score` -- float

`enabled` -- bool

I want to update `enabled` to `False` if there's another record with a higher score.

For example, if I have:

```
id | category | score | enabled
1  |  news    |  95   |    t
```

Then, after some operation, a new record with the same category is inserted:

```
id | category | score | enabled
1  |  news    |  95   |    t
2  |  news    |  100  |    f
```

Since the score for `id=2` is higher, I want to change `enabled` for `id=2` to `True` and change `enabled` for `id=1` to `False`.

I'm wondering if I can combine these operations into 1 query. Right now I do 2 `SELECT` queries to get the 2 records, then compare the scores locally, and then change the `enabled` value (if needed).

So simply,

```
SELECT id, score
FROM table
WHERE category = %s
AND enabled = True

SELECT id, score
FROM table
WHERE category = %s
AND id = (SELECT max(id) WHERE category=%s)

if score2>= score1:
    UPDATE table SET enabled = True
    WHERE id = id2

    UPDATE table SET enabled = False
    WHERE id = id1
```

It works, but it seems very inefficient. Any way to improve these queries?

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is more than one high score per category, i.e., two scores from the same category are equal and no score is higher than the two scores?

Comment: I want to choose the highest score to activate, basically.

Comment: @JChao: the question is what if there are two (or more rows) with "the highest score", when e.g an additional row with `id = 3, category = 'news' and score = 100` is inserted

Comment: Unrelated, but: using `float` (or `double precision`)  is rarely a good idea. Those are so called "approximate" data types. You can't guarantee that what you store is the same as what you read. And comparison is also somewhat shaky. Please read http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more details. Additional it seems `score` could easily be an `integer`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name interesting question...... I actually have never thought about it...... I'm guessing I'll just keep the original in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a single update:

```
update the_table 
  set enabled = (score = t.max_score)
from (
  select id, category, max(score) over (partition by category) as max_score
  from the_table
  where category = 'news'
) t
where t.id = the_table.id
  and t.category = the_table.category;
```

This will set the `enabled` flags for all rows with the same category in a single statement.

Online example: https://rextester.com/DXR80618

If you happen to have more than one row with the same highest score for one category, the above statement will change `enabled` to `true` for all of, .

E.g.

```
id | category | score
---+----------+------
 1 | news     |    95
 2 | news     |   100
 3 | news     |   100
```

If you don't want that, and e.g. always pick the one with the lowest `id` to be the enabled row, you can use the following:

```
update the_table 
  set enabled = (rn = 1)
from (
   select id, category, 
          row_number() over (partition by category order by score desc, id) as rn
   from the_table
   where category = 'news'
) t
where t.id = the_table.id
  and t.category = the_table.category;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JPA61125

Comment: I assume that `where category = 'news'` is a mistake? Also, `t.category = the_table.category` should be unnecessary.

Comment: @helios35: no it's not a mistake. The orginal question also does this for one single category (`category = %s`) . You are right, if `id` is the primary key, then the additional join in the WHERE clause is unnecessary